# Shared Element Transitions not working on Show/Hide fragments

Tags: android, android-transitions

I want to have snapchat like interface. Got two fragments and when going from one to other, i would like to just hide/show than 'replace' as they are heavy to create(nested fragments). But shared element transition is not working on show/hide. Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or a similar) problem, where the transition worked correctly when using [`replace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) but broke when using [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) and [`hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)). What fixed it for me was calling [`setReorderingAllowed(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setReorderingAllowed(boolean)) on the transaction.

Comment: This indeed caused the animation to start, there is a glitch however. For a moment before the exit transition starts, all the views disappear, causing nasty flickering effect. @Karakuri did you observe such thing as well?